# Why aren't active application's icon and name shown in launchbar Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Tags: 20.04, launcher, shortcuts

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1. Up to now the specific icon of my running application was shown in the launchbar. But now I see only the black placeholder. While hovering over the placeholder, the name of the application „SimpleDialog“ given at the desktop file isn‘t shown, but the name "TestSimpleDialog.Main".

My application is started by a desktop shortcut launcher. This is the desktopfile stored in /home/frizi/Schreibtisch:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SimpleDialog
Name[en]=FZsimpleDialogue
Comment=FriZi Simple Dialogue
Type=Application
Exec=java --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar "/media/frizi/FriZiDaten/Anwendungsdaten/FZfotoArchiv/JavaApplikation/SampleDialog.jar"
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=false
Icon=/home/frizi/.local/share/icon/iconPapagei80.png
Categories=Utility
```

There were no effects by the following modifications:

- adding the line StartupWMClass="TestSimpleDialog.Main", "TestSimpleDialog.Main" in the desktop file
- storing the desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications

Is there any idea to get the wanted effect?
Thanks for your help.